# Page Layout Change Set Not Changing once deployed

Tags: page-layout, change-set

I have been struggling with a change set.  I included the fields and the profiles plus the page layout, yet when I deploy it, the change to the Case page layout don't automatically change.  The fields are available to put into the page layout, but shouldn't they go in automatically.  I've double checked the permissions and they are set to visible.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Are there record types for your Case object? If so, add them to your change set as well. That should do the trick.

Comment: I just looked and the only record types I have are for the Account object.

Answer (score 1):

Did a new page layout get created in Production (or whatever your destination environment is)? If the name of the layout is different in your source organization, then it will appear as a separate layout and you will have to manually assign it to profiles.

Also, I believe that profile-layout assignments do not deploy, so you might want to check that your new layout is connected to the profile you are logged in with.

Comment: I think my problem is that the Case Page Layout is different than my Feed Layout.  So the case feed isn't matching what is in the sandbox.  I created a new Case Layout that clones what the custom case feed layout has on it and I hope this fixes the problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue, and one more thing I found is:

- you need to manually change the Page layout Assignment

Go to setup -> object Manager -> your object
then Page Layouts, and then in the top right click the button labeled Page Layout Assignment